# Curl command to copy a .sh file from AWS S3 location

Tags: amazon-web-services, curl, amazon-s3

What is curl command(in a .config file) to copy a .sh file from AWS S3 bucket.
To copy fluent installer file from a S3 location and install in the EC2 instance

i Need to replace below command to

curl -L https://toolbelt.treasuredata.com/sh/install-amazon1-td-agent3.sh

copy from S3 location

Comment: What do you mean by ".config file"? Can you show an example that uses curl?

Comment: Please edit your question to provide more information. For example, tell us what you are trying to accomplish and _WHY_. Also, what have you tried and what problems have you had?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein done

Comment: I'm having difficulty understanding what you mean by "replace below command". Are you saying that you want to retrieve an object from S3? If the object is public, you can use exactly the same command, but point to the S3 file instead. The URL is provided in the S3 management console, and it will look similar to `https://bucket-name.s3.amazonaws.com/file.sh` What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you mean a `.config` file that would be deployed with something like Elastic Beanstalk.

Firstly, I would highly recommend that you **turn off** the bucket's public availability if it is sensitive data.

Secondly, for this process, you should create a new IAM Policy (or a new Role), with access to the specific file in the Bucket you want to copy. Again, I am assuming Elastic Beanstalk for this answer.

> Elastic Beanstalk environments spin up with a default Role named:
> `"aws-elasticbeanstalk-ec2-role"`.

Here is an example Policy that you can create, and then attach to the Role:

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Action": ["s3:GetObject"],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::your-bucket-name/your-file.txt"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

The `.config` file contents should then be as follows:

```sh
Resources:
  AWSEBAutoScalingGroup:
    Metadata:
      AWS::CloudFormation::Authentication:
        S3Auth:
          type: "s3"
          buckets: ["your-bucket-name"]
          roleName: "aws-elasticbeanstalk-ec2-role"

files:
  "/path/to/your-file.txt" :
    mode: "000644"
    owner: root
    group: root
    authentication: "S3Auth"
    source: https://s3.REGION.amazonaws.com/your-bucket-name/your-file.txt
```

Replace:

- `REGION` with your Bucket's region,
- `your-bucket-name` with the Bucket's name,
- `your-file.txt` with your file's name.

---

### What this does

`.config` files are run before initialisation, and therefore allow you to *do things* before your code is run.

The code here creates a new file on the instance that it's deployed to, and copies the contents from the target in the S3 Bucket.

This file therefore exists before your own code is run, and you can safely use it at runtime.